# nUnit / moq - why does my mock always return false?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I'm new to unit testing with nUnit and Moq and have run into an issue seting behaviours for a method in a dbprovider.

I'm tryin to test a validation method that invokes an Exists method in ICoDbProvider. When false, the method throws an excpetion, and it is working nice. When true, the method should go ahead until the `return true;` statement at the end of the method.

**This is the method tested:**

```
private bool ValidateReciboCajaModel(ReciboCajaModel model)
{
        if (model == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("El modelo ha llegado nulo");

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.AccionARealizar))
            throw new ArgumentException("No se ha definido una Acción a realizar");

        if (!_accionARealizarService.Exists(new AccionARealizarEntity(model)))
            throw new ArgumentException(@"No es una ""acción a realizar"" válida");


        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.CentroCostos))
            throw new ArgumentException("No se ha definido ningún centro de costos");

        if (!_centroCostosService.Exists(new CentroCostosEntity(model)))
            throw new Exception("No es un centro de costos válido");

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.CuentaIngresoDinero))
            throw new Exception("No es una cuenta de Ingreso válida");

        if (!_terceroService.Exists(new TerceroEntity(model)))
            throw new Exception("No es un tercero registrado");

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.Tercero))
            throw new Exception("No es un tercero válido");

        if (!_tipoReciboCajaService.Exists(new TipoReciboCajaEntity(model)))
            throw new Exception("No es un recibo de caja registrado");

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.TipoReciboCaja))
            throw new Exception("No es un recibo de caja válido");

        if (!(0 < model.ValorPagado && model.ValorPagado <= 999999999999d))
            throw new Exception("El valor pagado no es válido");

        return true;

}
```

The test was originally generated by Intellitest, and it generated a scaffolding for private method testing.

**The test method looks like this.**

```
    [Test]
    [PexGeneratedBy(typeof(ReciboCajaBizTest))]
    [PexRaisedException(typeof(TargetInvocationException))]
    public void ValidateReciboCajaModel_ValidModel()
    {
        bool b;
        TargetInvocationException receivedException = new TargetInvocationException(null);

        ReciboCajaModel s1 = new ReciboCajaModel();
        var accionARealizarService = new Mock<ICoDbProvider>();
        var centroCostosService = new Mock<ICoDbProvider>();
        var terceroService = new Mock<ICoDbProvider>();
        var tipoReciboCajaService = new Mock<ICoDbProvider>();

        s1.TipoReciboCaja = "RC0";
        s1.Numero = 0;
        s1.Tercero = "tercero existente";
        s1.AccionARealizar = "some action";
        s1.FechaElaboracion = default(DateTime);
        s1.CentroCostos = "cc1";
        s1.CuentaIngresoDinero = "Débito";
        s1.ValorPagado = 1000000d;

        accionARealizarService.Setup(m => m.Exists(new AccionARealizarEntity(s1))).Returns(true);
        centroCostosService.Setup(m => m.Exists(new CentroCostosEntity(s1))).Returns(true);
        terceroService.Setup(m => m.Exists(new TerceroEntity(s1))).Returns(true);
        tipoReciboCajaService.Setup(m => m.Exists(new TipoReciboCajaEntity(s1))).Returns(true);

        ReciboCajaBiz s0 = new ReciboCajaBiz(null, accionARealizarService.Object, centroCostosService.Object,terceroService.Object,tipoReciboCajaService.Object);

        b = this.ValidateReciboCajaModel(s0, s1);

        Assert.AreEqual(true, b);
    }
```

This is the case everything in the Model is right and the method should return a valid flag.

I have this weird behaviour while debugging. Right after seting Mocks behaviour I called in Watch window the method, and it return false, as shown in the picture

[image: debug shows the behaviour is not working as set]

I also have a method that tests the accionARealizar object does not exists, and it returns false as set. But I doubt it is working correctly.

**Update**

As requested in comments below, this is ReciboCajaModel

```
public class ReciboCajaModel
{
    [Required]
    [EnumDataType(enumType: typeof(TipoReciboCaja))]
    public string TipoReciboCaja { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Numero { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Tercero { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string AccionARealizar { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime FechaElaboracion { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CentroCostos { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// este campo no sólo enlaza la cuenta donde se hace el abono o accion a realizar, sino también la forma de pago
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public string CuentaIngresoDinero { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Range(0, 999999999999)]
    public double ValorPagado { get; set; }
}
```

and ReciboCajaBiz constructors and private members

```
    private ICoDbProvider _reciboCajaService;
    private ICoDbProvider _accionARealizarService;
    private ICoDbProvider _centroCostosService;
    private ICoDbProvider _terceroService;
    private ICoDbProvider _tipoReciboCajaService;

    public ReciboCajaBiz()
    {
        _reciboCajaService = new ReciboCajaService();
        _accionARealizarService = new AccionARealizarService();
    }

    public ReciboCajaBiz(ICoDbProvider reciboCajaService = null, ICoDbProvider accionARealizarService = null, ICoDbProvider centroCostosService = null, ICoDbProvider terceroService = null, ICoDbProvider tipoReciboCajaService = null)
    {
        _reciboCajaService = reciboCajaService == null ? new ReciboCajaService() : reciboCajaService;
        _accionARealizarService = accionARealizarService == null ? new AccionARealizarService() : accionARealizarService;
        _centroCostosService = centroCostosService == null ? new CentroCostosService() : centroCostosService;
        _terceroService = terceroService == null ? new TerceroService() : terceroService;
        _tipoReciboCajaService = tipoReciboCajaService == null ? new TipoReciboCajaService() : terceroService;
    }
```

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. I can't copy and paste it and run it, there are too many things missing. The issue is _almost certainly_ that you forget to implement `GetHashCode` and `Equals` in `AccionARealizarEntity` - but I can't see it, so can't be sure.

Comment: @mjwills, I may be wrong, but the problem is on the mock. I can share the code of the constructor for the entity as well. In the mean time it only copies the accionARealizar value to a string member. No comparison done down there

Comment: A [mcve] really would be helpful, since it allows us to run the code and repro what you are seeing.

Comment: you are right @mjwills, however, you were just tryin to show I may not give you a full solution you could load in your own compiler, and the problem was elsewhere. Fortunately, the problem was identified without running my code. Focus is also important, and tht was fully explained.

Comment: It wasn't that I didn't understand the problem (I did - if you did what I said in my first comment your problem would have been solved). It is that a [mcve] makes **everyone's** life easier. Yes, there are multiple ways to solve it (as you found - you can solve it either by building equality checks into the class itself (my solution) or by doing the comparison check differently in `Moq` itself (Ralph's solution)). But the problem is, without a [mcve], I can't see if you have **already** done my solution. I don't want to waste your time telling you to do something you have already done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At a glance, your Moq expressions might not be matching as you expect.

Your trying to match on an object reference for your Exists() function, which means it will do an equality check on the object references - which won't match. You new'ing up two different objects.

```
_accionARealizarService.Exists(new AccionARealizarEntity(model))
```

[See here for more info on Moq Matching Arguments](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)

Change the `Setup` expression of the mock so it is more generous to see if this is the problem.

You can use `It.IsAny()` within the expression like.

```
accionARealizarService.Setup(m => m.Exists(It.IsAny<SiigoEntity>())).Returns(true);
```

Once that works you can get more specific with the `It.Is()` expression, to do object property inspection.

Comment: I understand your point, but does it realy matter since the entity is created based on the model passed to the method? and since, during testing time this model is the one created in the test, It needs to be done.

Comment: Besides, that line is in the method being tested.

Comment: Thank you @Ralph. I also try to clarify a bit what you suggested so the answer is explicit now.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was using object references in the behavior set of the mock. I was using this:

```
accionARealizarService.Setup(m => m.Exists(new AccionARealizarEntity(s1))).Returns(true);
```

But that will cause the test to create an object and compare this object with the object sent to the Exists method so it can validate the behavior. This will cause a call to `Equals` method and so it will always throw false.

To correctly validate the parameters sent to a mocked method, I should use this:

```
accionARealizarService.Setup(m => m.Exists(It.IsAny<CoEntity>())).Returns(true);
```

The `It.IsAny<CoEntity>`statement will indicate the mocked method behavior to not compare against a specific instance of the object but to validate if the object is a `CoEntity`.

I reached this conclusion and post this full answer based on @Ralph answer, which led me to the right path.

Comment: Then why not award the answer to @RalphWillgoss. Your self answer can remain to reinforce what was provided there. Win win for all involved.

Comment: I did edit his answer, but someone refused it. I consider the answer was not complete, I just tryed to clarify and make it straight forward. Whay shoud I do to do it best?